# jquery datatable fnAddData data manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I would like to wrap the content of each cell into a div with different classes that I put to a datatable using fnAddData. With other words: when I use

```
fnAddData(["a","b","c"])
```

I would like to see the next values in the table:

```
<div class="cellContent1">a</div>
<div class="cellContent2">b</div>
<div class="cellContent3">c</div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
    fnAddData(array){
    var resluarray =array.split(',');
    var resultstring; 
    for (var i = 0, l = resluarray .length; i++){
    resultstring += '<div class="+resluarray[i]+">+resluarray[i]+</div>';

    }
   return resultstring ;
    }
```

After that append the resultstring to your td or to your element .